# Using @Getter on Classes, Enums, etc

Tags: java, spring, lombok, accessor

I came across a code where `@Getter` was used on an enum declaration, I want to know if it's possible to use `@Getter` over an enum declaration and what purpose it serves?

As far as I know, `@Getter` generates getter methods on member variables. Am I missing something?

Is it possible to annotate the class with `@Getter` as well?

Comment: take a look at https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you check the [Lombok's **@Getter and @Setter** Reference](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter), you can see that:

> You can also put a @Getter and/or @Setter annotation on a class. In that case, it's as if you annotate all the non-static fields in that class with the annotation.

This means when you put `@Getter` in the Class/Enum level, it will generate `getters` for all non static members on this Class/Enum, as if you put `@Getter` for all those members repeatedly.

**Example:**

To illustrate this with an example both these two codes are equivalent:

Code 1:

```
@Getter
public enum MyEnum {
    private int member1;
    private int member2;
}
```

Code 2:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    @Getter
    private int member1;
    @Getter
    private int member2;
}
```

Here `getter` methods will be generated for both members.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Getter annotation, the constants are not important. But for all the other variables that you create there exists a getter method:

```
@Getter
public enum Test {
    TEST;

    private int variable;
}
```

So in this example you get only a getter method for the variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Added later**
I think @cнŝdk answer is much better. So, please use it.

**Originally wrote**

@Getter, @Setter, and @Data annotations are provided by **Lombok** library. 
@Data will generate both setters and getters.

Yes, these annotations can be used with both class and enum.

If you are using maven then you can add Lombok as your dependency as given below:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.12</version>
</dependency>
```

To know more about Lombok please visit https://projectlombok.org/.

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ then install Lombok Plugin for it.

Comment: How does this answers the OP question?

Answer (score 0):

We can annotate any field with @Getter and/or @Setter, to let lombok generate the default getter/setter automatically.
[Please refer here](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) to get more details.